# Firefox, how to remove form history for a single site

Tags: firefox, caching, history

How to remove form history for specific site?
I have a lot of useful autocomplete data in my firefox browser, however i'd like to remove all data for a single site. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Menu/History/Show all history** - in the search box enter desired word or URL, choose one of records, right mouse click and choose Forget about this site. Or you can use some of Firefox Form history addon.

Comment: If forgetting about this site, will new history be saved once I type new information in the fields?

Comment: Yes, of course. Otherwise you can use private browsing.